# consulta tabla SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Tengo una tabla SQL que contiene canton y CuentaDecanton. Lo que necesito es que la tabla me tome el registro de solamente del canton con mayor número (CuentaDecanton). Tiene que tener un resultado como en la segunda imagen adjunta. Gracias

[image: Adjunto una imagen 1]

[image: Adjunto imagen 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Sql Server puedes utilizar el operador top, que te devuelve el número de resultados solicitado. Si hubiese dos resultados iguales y quisieras obtener ambos, entonces le aplicarías WITH TIES

```
create table Cantones (canton varchar(100), cuentaDecanton int)
go
insert into Cantones (canton, cuentaDecanton)
values
('Montes de Oca',2),
('Tibás',1),
('Santo Domingo',1),
('San Carlos',1),
('La Unión',1);
go
Select top(1) * from Cantones
order by cuentaDecanton desc
go
```

[Top](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[image: Resultado]